# How do I fix having no internet while connected to NordVPN?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn

I use Ubuntu 20.04, newest version of NordVPN. It worked before, but one day it just stopped working. I figured this is the best place to ask for help.

Comment: Hello. That would be a good question to ask Nord VPN support.

Comment: David, could you give me the link to NordVPN chat support or something similar? Because I cant seem to find it.

Comment: support.nordvpn.com

Comment: No Raffles, i don't see a some form of contacting NordVPN on that site.